# I test the Iperf failed

Tags: linux, iperf

In my Server(CentOS7.2, address is `103.193.202.2`), I run the `iperf` server:

```
# iperf -u -s
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my Mac, I use bellow command to test my server.

```
$ iperf -u -c  103.193.202.2 -b 100M -P 5 
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 103.193.242.2, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size: 9.00 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  7] local 192.168.1.3 port 58906 connected with 103.193.242.2 port 5001
[  6] local 192.168.1.3 port 63984 connected with 103.193.242.2 port 5001
[  4] local 192.168.1.3 port 62739 connected with 103.193.242.2 port 5001
[  5] local 192.168.1.3 port 62128 connected with 103.193.242.2 port 5001
[  8] local 192.168.1.3 port 59654 connected with 103.193.242.2 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  7]  0.0-10.0 sec  4.42 MBytes  3.70 Mbits/sec
[  7] Sent 85471 datagrams
[  6]  0.0-10.0 sec  7.36 MBytes  6.17 Mbits/sec
[  6] Sent 85470 datagrams
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  4.41 MBytes  3.70 Mbits/sec
[  4] Sent 85470 datagrams
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  7.46 MBytes  6.25 Mbits/sec
[  5] Sent 85468 datagrams
[  8]  0.0-10.0 sec  8.22 MBytes  6.89 Mbits/sec
[  8] Sent 85469 datagrams
[SUM]  0.0-10.0 sec  31.9 MBytes  26.7 Mbits/sec
[  4] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
[  8] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
[  6] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
[  7] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
[  5] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
```

You see in my Mac there comes `WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.` 
And in my Server I did not get prints too. Why I test failed?